# Finding the actual tip radius of a spur gear with large pressure angle and low number of teeth

Tags: gears

I'm writing software to design standard spur gears that can have large pressure angles and low numbers of teeth.  I'm dealing with undercut issues fine but struggling with the teeth tips.  As pressure angle goes up and number of teeth go down the top land narrows, becomes zero width, and then becomes negative: effectively the tip moves inside the standard calculated tip diameter.

How would I derive the actual tip diameter using either module- or dp-based equations?

Some addenda: I'm using physical hob modelling to determine the profile shape rather than the more common involute/trochoid method but could probably adapt a solution using that if it produced an equivalent profile shape.  My understanding is that there's not a nice way of finding the trochoid/involute intersection and that iterative numerical solutions are required.  Physical modelling also provides the option of non-standard (asymmetric or unusual) teeth shapes.

Comment: AGMA standards 908 and 913 may have equations to determine your diameters. 908 does have an iterative solution for "inverse" involute calculations, but in my experience it only needs 6-7 iterations before you get an answer that's within 0.001%.

Comment: 0.001% is close enough, thanks, I'll have a look.